# Cap-Independence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, manifolds

I'm just trying to figure out something regarding Cap-Independence. The problem reads

$\partial S:= r(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,\sin 2t)$, $0\le t \le 2\pi;$

$\phi=z\,dzdx-6y^2dxdy$ ($\partial S $ represents the boundary of S).

The problem states: Show $\int \phi$ over S  cap-independent and use this fact to compute it.

Now it is is easy to find a $\phi = d\psi$ which implies that the form is exact and thus is cap-independent. However I am at a loss for how to apply any theorems or translations to use the fact that phi is cap-independent in the computation of this problem. (This is the first time I've encountered cap-independence).

Comment: By Stokes's theorem, we have $$\int_S d\psi = \int_{\partial S}\psi.$$

Comment: I was thinking of that approach but I wasn't quite sure if it would be using the fact of "cap-Independence" to solve it. Also, I'm not quite sure what to integrate over. My weak point is really with parametrization understanding.

Comment: Cap-independence means that $\int_{S_1} \phi = \int_{S_2} \phi$ whenever $\partial S_1 = \partial S_2$. Thus, assuming that $\int_S \phi$ exists, one can compute this integral without knowing what $S$ actually is, only knowing that its boundary is the curve parametrised by $r(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, \sin 2t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. If we take $\psi = (2y^3+\frac12 z^2)dx$, then we would have $$\int_S \phi = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left(2\sin^3t + \tfrac12 \sin^2 2t\right)(-\sin t)\,dt.$$

Comment: That makes sense. The only thing left that I don't quite understand is why -sint?

Comment: We have $dx = d(\cos t) = -\sin t\,dt$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks for all the help, it makes sense now. One last question. If I had a form $\phi$= -x^3dydz-y^3+3z(x^2+y^2)dxdy , would $\psi$ = x^3zdy - y^3zdx make sense?

Comment: Yes, assuming that $-y^3$ was the coefficient in front of $dz\,dx$, as the term $dz\,dx$ is missing from your formula for $\phi$.

Comment: Ops, it should be -y^3dzdx in the $\phi$.

Comment: It's all right then.